# How to turn off text overwrite mode in text editors?

Tags: text-editor, overwrite, mode

I have used DevC++ and similar environments also have this application. While the overwrite mode is on the code overwrites instead of code moving to right.

Comment: This depends on the editor. Usually the `insert` key on your keyboard toggles this though. There's also often an indicator in the bottom right of the window that can be clicked to toggle it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue can be solved by using fn + insert(print screen) in Windows 8 or above and insert key in lower versions.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Kokul says, you can press the `Insert` Key. If your Windows machine does *not* have a physical `Insert` key, you can press the virtual one, which you can find by pressing:

`Windows Key` > `Ease of Access Keyboard Settings` > `Use the On-Screen Keyboard`

Then press the `Insert` key which is located on the virtual keyboard to the right of the `Enter` key. Pressing the virtual key will behave like pressing the physical `Insert` Key.